# HelpStack: Predefined colors not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to integrate [HelpStack](https://github.com/happyfoxinc/helpstack-android) with my system but everytime I tried to add it I got compilation error about predefined colors, I'm wondering why predefined android colors are not working with this project, here is the error I got:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@color/white').
```

I know that this can be done using res/colors.xml, but I want to use predefined colors.

Comment: android:background="@android:color/white"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add on for @MD's answer, If you have defined white color in your resource file, Then confirm your file location.

I mean, `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` should be in `res\values` folder,

For example, if you defined it in `res\values-v21` folder, and run your app under API level 21 means, which also will cause the resource not found exception.